# the complexity of Lanczos method

Tags: eigenvector, reference-request, computational-complexity

Hi, all

I am working on an algorithm which uses Lanczos method to compute K smallest eigenvalue(and their eigenvectos) of a sparse matrix, just want some information or links about the complexity of Lanczos method.

Thank you

Comment: Added reference-request and cs.cc tags

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Complexity analysis of Lanczos seems to be hard to find in the literature. Here are two leads, that might help a bit.

For the largest eigenvalue, you might find the complexity analysis in the following paper to be useful.

[Estimating the Largest Eigenvalue by the Power and Lanczos Algorithms with a Random Start](http://academiccommons.columbia.edu/download/fedora_content/download/ac:143006/CONTENT/cucs-465-89.pdf) by *J. Kuczyński and H. Woźniakowski*

A very important point raised in the above paper is that even if an eigenvalue is easily estimable, its corresponding eigenvector can be computationally hard to estimate!

Also see Lemma 2 of [Fast algorithms for approximate semidefinite programming ...](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~arora/pubs/mw-focs.pdf) by *S. Arora, E. Hazan, and S. Kale*, for additional results.

Answer (score 2):

Chapter 9 = Lanczos Methods, of "matrix computations", Golub, van Loan, John Hopkins univ press.